# simple_form association doesn't save belongs_to id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I have a `recipient` and `category` model. It's a simple association of 1 category has many recipients. When I try to update the `recipient` form and assign a `category`, it won't save to the record. If I use the console and update a record manually, e.g. `Recipient.update(9, category_id: 13)`, I see the correct category assigned to the recipient but when I try to edit/update the record, it won't save to the new chosen category.

Here is my `recipient` model

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
end
```

Here is my `category` model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipients
  validates :category, presence: true

  default_scope { order('category')}
end
```

here is the `recipient` controller

```
class RecipientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recipients = Recipient.order(:recipient_name).page(params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @recipient = Recipient.new
  end

  def show
    @recipient = Recipient.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @recipient = Recipient.new(recipient_params)
    if @recipient.save
      redirect_to recipients_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @recipient = Recipient.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @recipient = Recipient.find(params[:id])

    recipient_params = params.require(:recipient).permit(:recipient_name, :alternate_name, :description, :city, :state, :country, category_attributes: [:category, :id])
    @recipient.update_attributes(recipient_params)

    redirect_to recipient_path(id: @recipient.id)
  end

  def destroy
    @recipient = Recipient.find(params[:id])
    @recipient.destroy

    redirect_to recipients_path
  end

  private
  def recipient_params
    params.require(:recipient).permit(:recipient_name, :alternate_name, :description, :city, :state, :country, product_attributes: [:product_name, recipient_products: [:recipient_id, :product_id]], channel_attributes: [:channel_name, recipient_channels: [:recipient_id, :channel_id]],  category_attributes: [:id, :category])
  end

end
```

here is the `edit` view

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Edit <%= @recipient.recipient_name %></h2>

    <%= simple_form_for @recipient do |form| %>
      <%= form.error_notification %>
      <%= form.input :recipient_name, placeholder: 'Recipient', label: 'Recipient Name' %>
      <%= form.input :alternate_name, placeholder: 'Alternate Name' %>
      <%= form.association :category, label_method: :category, value_method: :id %>
      <%= form.input :description, placeholder: 'Description'%>
      <%= form.input :city, placeholder: 'City'%>
      <%= form.input :state, placeholder: 'State' %>
      <%= form.input :country, as: :country, priority: ['US', 'CA'] %>
      <%= form.button :submit, 'Update Recipient', {:class=>"btn btn-secondary"} %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", :back, {:class=>"btn btn-default"} %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my `routes.rb` file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'
  resources :media_points
  resources :products
  resources :channels
  resources :recipients
  resources :media_point_products
  resources :distributions
  resources :categories do
    resources :recipients
  end
  get '/listing' => "listing#index"
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: I believe you need to change the params method in your controller.  Try changing:   category_attributes: [:category, :id]    to     category_id: :category_id_from_form_here

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it as an answer since the format is a pain in comments:

Change your recipient_params private method from: 
 `category_attributes: [:category, :id]`

to

```
 category_id: param_that_has_category_id_here
```

Also, you have two routes for recipients and it is going to utilize the first matching route which is not the nested recipients in categories route you have further down.  If the first change in your private method didn't fix it I would specify the nested situation in simpleform doing as follows since you are probably looking to use the nested route:

```
  simple_form_for [@category, @recipient], url: 'nested_route_path_here' do |f|
```

Just add   `@category = Category.new` to your new action in the recipients controller and then in your create action you'll have the category param sent via params[:category_id]

Comment: I understand most of your answer but getting lost on the correct syntax for `category_id: param_that_has_category_id_here` I'm not sure what to put for  `param_that_has_category_id_here`

Comment: Your form is submitting a value for the category id, whatever attribute you gave in your form for that value should be whitelisted in your params method and assigned to "category_id" so Rails properly handles the association.